# Use Dynamic Query into a fetch cycle

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a many customer databases. I need to execute different type of SELECT queries on each customerDb: each SELECT will extract just one value.

Then I want to put each SELECT result for each CustomerDB in a #tempTable and finally collect all resultset in one-shot for all CustomerDBs in a table like this:

| customerDB | value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| customerA | 10000 | 1234 | 456 |
| customerB | 5000 | 1000 | 999 |
| customerC | 5555 | 1432 | 765 |

I've tried to use the EXEC(@query) to redirect the result into a variable and then use the variabile into an INSERT command but it doesn't work.
Any help???

Here is my script:

```
DECLARE c_db_names CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name NOT IN('master', 'model','msdb','tempdb')
DECLARE @db_name NVARCHAR (150)
DECLARE @ServerName nvarchar(50) = @@SERVERNAME
CREATE TABLE  #temp_tb( [serverName] [varchar](50) NULL, [tenantCode] [varchar](10) NULL, [value1] [varchar](10) NULL, [value2] [varchar](10) NULL )
OPEN c_db_names
FETCH c_db_names INTO @db_name
WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @firtsQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @secondQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @firtsResult NVARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @secondResult NVARCHAR(10)

    SELECT @firtsQuery = 'select count(*) FROM [' + @db_name + '].[dbo].table1 where ...'
    SELECT @secondQuery = 'select count(*) FROM [' + @db_name + '].[dbo].table2 where ...'

    exec @firstResult = (@firtsQuery)
    exec @secondResult = (@secondQuery)
    
    INSERT INTO #temp_tb (serverName,tenantCode,value1,value2) VALUES (@ServerName, @db_name, @firstResult, @secondResult)
FETCH c_db_names INTO @db_name
END
CLOSE c_db_names
DEALLOCATE c_db_names

SELECT * FROM #TEMP_TB
DROP TABLE #TEMP_TB
```

Comment: Honestly, when you need to be able to (easily) query your databases like this is normally a sign that you should not be using separate databases.

Comment: As for why what you have isn't working, `exec @firtsRestul = (@firtsQuery)` isn't valid syntax. Use an `OUTPUT` parameter (hint, you can't do that with `EXEC(@SQL)` syntax, you should be using `sys.sp_executesql`), or `INSERT` into your temporary table directly from your dynamic statement.

Comment: Also, though it seems silly, I strongly recommend spelling correctly in your SQL. Your variable names don't consistently spell result or second, and you don't spell first correctly either. Such typographical errors in your code can actually be a nightmare later down the line. To cement this, the above will error with `Must declare the scalar variable "@secndResult".` because you declared the variable as `@secondResult`.

Comment: yes, I've wrote wrongly the variables. It was a mistake. I'm interested in applying the sp_executesql. could you please provide an example in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to have a play with something like the below, this goes through each database excluding the ones in the NOT IN.

This example goes through each database making sure we have the right users added.

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb N'IF ''?'' NOT IN (''master'', ''model'', ''msdb'', ''tempdb'')
BEGIN
    USE [?]
    IF USER_ID(''NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'') IS NULL
    BEGIN
        PRINT ''Using Database '' + DB_NAME()

        PRINT ''Creating database user NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'' 
        CREATE USER [NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE] FOR LOGIN [NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE]

        PRINT ''Granting db_owner permission NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE''  
        EXEC sp_addrolemember N''db_owner'', N''NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE''
    END
END';
```